# Difference between position and sort_order in customer install script

Tags: magento2, customer, catalog, eav, setup-script

I'm trying to understand how the install works for EAV entities in Magento2.
I see that in the `installEntities` method from the `Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup` class, the attributes have 2 fields with the same value [`position` and `sort_order`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Setup/CustomerSetup.php#L161).
but in the catalog module in the `Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetup` there is only the [`sort_order`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Setup/CategorySetup.php#L88) field.
Please explain what's the difference between them (if any) and for what is each one used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's used like an alias but I don't get why both `position` and `sort_order` are part of this script.

The only place I've noticed the use of the `position` in the Customer module is under `Magento/Customer/Model/ResourceModel/Setup/PropertyMapper.php` :

```
public function map(array $input, $entityTypeId)
{
    return [
        'is_visible' => $this->_getValue($input, 'visible', 1),
        'is_system' => $this->_getValue($input, 'system', 1),
        'input_filter' => $this->_getValue($input, 'input_filter', null),
        'multiline_count' => $this->_getValue($input, 'multiline_count', 0),
        'validate_rules' => $this->_getValue($input, 'validate_rules', null),
        'data_model' => $this->_getValue($input, 'data', null),
        'sort_order' => $this->_getValue($input, 'position', 0),
        'is_used_in_grid' => $this->_getValue($input, 'is_used_in_grid', 0),
        'is_visible_in_grid' => $this->_getValue($input, 'is_visible_in_grid', 0),
        'is_filterable_in_grid' => $this->_getValue($input, 'is_filterable_in_grid', 0),
        'is_searchable_in_grid' => $this->_getValue($input, 'is_searchable_in_grid', 0),
    ];
}
```

This method is used to map input attribute properties to storage representation.

It is used in the `addAttribute()` method in `Magento/Eav/Setup/EavSetup.php` :

```
public function addAttribute($entityTypeId, $code, array $attr)
{
    $entityTypeId = $this->getEntityTypeId($entityTypeId);

    $data = array_replace(
        ['entity_type_id' => $entityTypeId, 'attribute_code' => $code],
        $this->attributeMapper->map($attr, $entityTypeId)
    );
    ...
}
```

However, I don't see this `addAttribute()` method being called in the Customer install script as it inserts multiple rows at the same time:

```
    if ($data) {
        $this->getSetup()->getConnection()
            ->insertMultiple($this->getSetup()->getTable('customer_form_attribute'), $data);
    }
```

Maybe that's the reason why both `position` and `sort_order` are specified as the `addAttribute()` is not called.

Comment: Ah. Good finding. I guess the `sort_order` is just a redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `sort_order` is the correct one as it is used at `\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup::addAttribute`.

```
$sortOrder = isset($attr['sort_order']) ? $attr['sort_order'] : null;
```

And its also the column name in `customer_eav_attribute` table.

When looking into `catalog_eav_attribute`, the `position` field is always `0`. It seems its not used. Even if you change the position value the admin remains unchanged.